# Is foreign aid loans?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics

I see that America is giving tons of foreign aids. Is that loans?? Or just money without expecting any returns?? Help me understand the loans given to other countries and aids.Also during military aids who is paying for the soldiers??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the discipline of Economics but about information discoverable by using Google.

Comment: Question could perhaps be migrated to politics.SE? There are many variants. Foreign aid can be a loan (which doesn't mean there is an expectation of returns) or direct payments. International donors do sometimes pay for salaries for soldiers, teachers, etc. but do not necessarily handle payroll themselves (instead you give a lump sum to a central government office). Some things that are counted as “aid” actually go to private contractors (from the donor country or not) providing services in the country or are coming back as contracts for big companies from the donor country.